# Multiple SET statements SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created a table which has 3 columns, Hunger, Thirst and Happiness.
But i need to create  a procedure that changes the Happiness value accordingly to Hunger and Thirst Stats.
This is what i made:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StatusRefresh AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Status 
    SET Hunger = Hunger - 5, Thirst = Thirst - 5

    IF (Hunger > 50 & Thirst > 50)
        THEN
           SET Happiness = Happiness + 5
    ELSE
           SET Happiness = Happiness - 5
 END
```

I'm pretty sure that the error is due to my If statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StatusRefresh AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Status 
    SET Hunger = Hunger - 5,
        Thirst = Thirst - 5,
        Happiness = (CASE WHEN Hunger > 50 and Thirst > 50 THEN Happiness + 5
                          ELSE Happiness - 5
                     END)
END;
```

you may need to adjust the limits, depending on whether you want the `hunger` and `thirst` values from *before* the update or *after*.  As written, this uses the value *before* the update.